# GroupBy based on condition Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a peculiar problem to which I don't see an easy solution (and efficient one). I have a list of addresses (more than 10M) with different user_time_active. I also have count per user_time_active and sum.

 such as this:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----+---------------+
|     address|   user_time_active|count|            sum|
+------------+-------------------+-----+---------------+
|        183b| 0.5517241379310345|    1|              9|
|        183b|                0.0|    2|              9|
|        183b| 0.6226415094339622|    1|              9|
|        183b|0.21649484536082475|    1|              9|
|        183b|0.49295774647887325|    1|              9|
|        183b| 0.7183098591549296|    1|              9|
|        183b|                1.0|    1|              9|
|        183b| 0.9705882352941176|    1|              9|
+------------+-------------------+-----+---------------+
```

My objective is to calculate percentage FOR EACH ADDRESS what % of users under one address was active 0 times, all the time or anything in between (such as != 0 & != 1) 
 Therefore here, expected result would be:

```
+------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+-------+
|     address|   time_active_0|   time_active_mix|   time_active_1|    sum|
+------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+-------+
|        183b|               2|                 6|               1|      9|
|        ....|             ...|               ...|             ...|    ...|
+------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+-------+
```

I know I can somehow use IF loops here but with such quantities execution of the loop will be painfully slow. Can anyone advise how can I use .agg with functions so I can obtain my result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering the solution, I found one! End table looks a bit different, but it works!

I use:

```
df = df.withColumn("status", f.when(f.col("user_time_active") == 1, 1) \
       .when(f.col("user_time_active") == 0, 0) \
       .otherwise("mix"))
```

Then I group by address + status, using .agg with sum on number of occurences, et voila! :)